# Show that the set of singular 2x2 matrices under the usual operations is not a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I don't know how to approach this question. Should I just check for all properties of a vector space using this matrice and show that it doesn't hold true for one of them? I'm not sure how to approach this question.

Answer (score 1):

Let define the following matrices:
$$A:=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},B:=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Then, $A$ and $B$ are singular while $A+B$ is invertible.

**Exercise.** Prove that the set of $2\times 2$ non-singular matrices is not a vector-space.